# Pyspark -> StringIndexer: "None" value is replaced with number

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have data frame which has several "None" values.
After transforming string columns to float columns by **StringIndexer**, the "None" values are replaced with number.

**Question:**
How can I transform string columns to float columns, but keep "None" values as "None"?

Thanks.

```
# Transform nominal attributes to numeric attributes
for columnName, columnType in self.rawData.dtypes:
    if columnType == "string":
        self.rawData = PreProcess.TransformNominalToNumeric(self.rawData, columnName)



class PreProcess:
    @staticmethod
    def TransformNominalToNumeric(dataFrame, inputColumn):
        """Transformation of nominal attributes into numeric"""
        outputColumn = inputColumn + "_index"
        indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = inputColumn, outputCol = outputColumn, handleInvalid = "keep")
        indexer = indexer.fit(dataFrame)
        dataFrame = indexer.transform(dataFrame)
        dataFrame = dataFrame.drop(inputColumn)
        dataFrame = dataFrame.withColumnRenamed(outputColumn, inputColumn)
        return dataFrame
```

Answer (score 4):

[Since `keep`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer@handleInvalid:org.apache.spark.ml.param.Param[String])

> put invalid data in a special additional bucket, at index numLabels

you can replace values manually after `transform`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

dataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(["a", None, "b"], "string").toDF("value")

inputColumn = "value"
outputColumn = inputColumn + "_index"

indexer = StringIndexer(
     inputCol=inputColumn, outputCol=outputColumn, handleInvalid="keep"
).fit(dataFrame)

(indexer
   .transform(dataFrame)
   .withColumn(outputColumn, when(col(outputColumn) == len(indexer.labels), None).otherwise(col(outputColumn)))
   .show())
# +-----+-----------+
# |value|value_index|
# +-----+-----------+
# |    a|        0.0|
# | null|       null|
# |    b|        1.0|
# +-----+-----------+
```

but if you plan to use `pyspark.ml` later, there is no value in that. No `pyspark.ml` algorithm accepts `NULL`s, so you have to impute, drop, and encode (like here), depending on the type and requirements, these before proceeding.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped me.
After transforming nominal attributes to numeric I used **Imputer** to replace "Null" values with Mean.